# C# Call to unmanaged Delphi DLL returns a partially corrputed structure

Tags: c#, delphi, structure, unmanaged, ref

I'm having some issues where data in a structure that I pass to an unmanaged DLL written in Delphi (version unknown) seems to be getting corrupted.  Would someone please do a sanity check on my code.

The project is build with VS2012 targeting the X86 platform.  It is running on Win7 32.  .NET Framework 4.0

Here is the structure of the Delphi struct.

```
type
  TReportingEvent = packed record
    EventID: integer;
    MACAddress: array[0..5] of byte;
    EventSequence : word;
    FormatID: word;
    RawEvent: array[0..31] of byte;
end;
  pTReportingEvent = ^TReportingEvent;
```

Here is the structure defined in my C# project

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct REPORTING_EVENT
{
    public Int32 EventID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE)]
    public Byte[] MacAddress;

    public UInt16 EventSequence;
    public UInt16 FormatID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_EVENT_SIZE)]
    public Byte[] RawEvent;

    public REPORTING_EVENT(Int32 iEventID)
    {
        this.EventID = iEventID;
        this.EventSequence = 0;
        this.FormatID = 0;
        this.MacAddress = new Byte[MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE];
        this.RawEvent = new Byte[MAX_EVENT_SIZE];
    }
};
```

The constants are defined as such

```
public const int MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE = 6;
public const int MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 32;
```

The Delphi unmanaged function is defined as this

```
[DllImport("ipdox.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int GetEventEx(ref REPORTING_EVENT Event);
```

The code where I call the function is this

```
Console.WriteLine("Reporting Event.  Event index = " + m.WParam.ToString());
REPORTING_EVENT rptEvent = new REPORTING_EVENT((Int32)m.WParam);
long iRptResult = GetEventEx(ref rptEvent);
```

I build just fine and the code executes without any issues, but the data displayed is not as expected.  Specifically The two word values and the raw event byte data.

I'm expecting something like this (which utilizes the same DLLs I use).

> 11/11/2013 12:09:08 PM - Event received: 74 Sender: 0019BA0216D9 Event
> Sequence no: 1206 Reporting Format ID: 0 Raw data :  99 98 18 31 2A A1
> AA 1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00

But I get this in my output.  The format is some random number, the event id is correct, as is the MAC.  Everything else doesn't seem right.

Reporting Event.
Event index = 38
New Event Pre Build Info String, format id =  7921 and Event Seq = 8332
New Event Event ID: 38
MAC Address: 00:19:BA:02:16:D9
Event Sequence: 8332
Format ID: 7921
Raw Event:
Hex of raw event                 5FF0904046285DE0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
character of raw event    _d?@F(]à                          
binary of raw event         9524014464704093224000000000000000000000000

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, or if you see that I missed something.

Thanks

Comment: the struct and the record match. It's SSCCE time.

Comment: From your comment on Gary's the answer you might consider to edit your answer, showing the real problem and possibly add your solution as answer. As it stands it might be missleading for future readers of the question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is be that Delphi record packing does not match your definition, been a while since I played with records in Delphi, but try adding 2 bytes of filler immediately after MacAddress (or change your struct layout packing to 4). To be honest, I thought the default Delphi "record packing" matched your declaration, but the described behavior suggests this is not so.

Comment: Delphi packing matches the C# packing

Comment: Did you even try it? this is where it "breaks", as I said, I thought your declared packing matches what I thought it should be, but the behavior suggests otherwise. If it is still broken, I would not be surprised.

Comment: LOL, that was not my comment, that was David's.  I haven't tried it yet, but will in the next hour or two.  Thanks for the response so far.

Comment: Neither worked.  I tried putting in a byte array after the mac address, and tried multiple sizes (2 to 8) just for grins.  I also set the pack size to 4 and no go either.

Comment: don't accept an answer that is wrong, please. That helps nobody.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. It is not related to what I demonstrated. The initialization of the DLL (loading some accounts) has caused a problem. Thanks for the help and your valuable time